# Ler Javascript em todos os itens do ForEach

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

Galera, eu tenho um foreach que carrega varios inputs, e quero que meu codigo javascript leia em todos os inputs gerados pelo foreach, alguém pode me dar uma dica de como fazer ?

Exemplo

```
<c:forEach items="${listaServico}" var="lista"

<input id="txt1" type="text"  onkeyup="calcular()">
<input id="txt2" type="text"  onkeyup="calcular()">
<input id="result" type="text"">

</c:forEach>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function calcular(){


    var valor1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txt1').value, 10);
    var valor2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txt2').value, 10);
    document.getElementById('result').value = valor1 * valor2;
}

</script>
```

É para calcular o valor do primeiro input e do segundo e lançar no terceiro input.

O problema é que só carrega o JavaScript no primeiro item do forEach, o restante não funciona o JavaScript.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, eu agradeceria muito.

Comment: Primeiro que você não pode definir o atributo `id` de um elemento dentro de um laço de repetição. O atributo `id` define um elemento único na página e, se houverem vários com mesmo `id`, o navegador irá ignorar. Por isso funciona apenas o primeiro, pois ele será único. Da maneira que está estruturado o HTML talvez complique fazer o que precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Assim como o Anderson já mencionou é imperativo trocar `id` por `class`, pois não é permitido termos `id`'s repetidos numa página. Por isso a parte inicial de geração do html deve ficar:

```
<c:forEach items="${listaServico}" var="lista"

<input class="txt1" type="text"  onkeyup="calcular()"><!-- class="txt1" em vez de id-->
<input class="txt2" type="text"  onkeyup="calcular()">
<input class="result" type="text"">

</c:forEach>
```

Em javascript agora podemos fazer o calculo de cada par de elementos utilizando a função para ir buscar todos de uma classe `getElementsByClassName` e um `for`:

```
function calcular(){
    var valores1 = document.getElementsByClassName('txt1'); //lista de todos os valores1
    var valores2 = document.getElementsByClassName('txt2'); //lista de todos os valores2
    var resultados = document.getElementsByClassName('result'); //lista de resultados

    for (let i = 0; i < valores1.length; ++i){ //para cada conjunto
        let num1 = parseFloat(valores1[i].value); //ir buscar o 1º valor como float
        let num2 = parseFloat(valores2[i].value); //ir buscar o 2º valor como float
        resultados[i].value = num1 * num2; //calcular e apresentar no resultado respetivo
    }
}
```